# jQuery append content of multiple URLs in array with .get/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, get

is it possible to append content of each URL in the array to given container from the list of URls with jQuery?

Like this:

```
<li class="contacts"><a href="index.php#contact1">Contact 1</a>
<li class="contacts"><a href="index.php#contact2">Contact 2</a>
<li class="contacts"><a href="index.php#contact3">Contact 3</a>
<li class="contacts"><a href="index.php#contact4">Contact 4</a>
```

I know how to get an array of URLs with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allLinks = $('li.contacts a').map(function(i,el) { return $(el).attr('href');     });
    console.log($(allLinks));
});
```

ok, I have an array of URLs in allLinks variable. I now want to append, say, content of #content element of each of this URLs with .get() function.

How to loop from 1st to the last one URL from array and append their content to my current page? It should basically end like this:

```
<div id="currentpage">
//#content of URL1
//#content of URL2
//#content of URL3
//#content of URL4
</div>
```

List of URLs is generated dynamically (this isn't problem).

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allLinks = $('li.contacts a').map(function(i,el) { return $(el).attr('href'); });
    console.log($(allLinks));

  var curr  = 0;
        if (curr++ > allLinks.length) curr = 0;

        $.get(allLinks[curr],function(data){
        var myContent = $(data).find('#content').children();
            jQuery('#wrapper').append(myContent);
   });
});
```

But without success. Any clue?

Comment: what response are you gettin in data ??

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:** (Load clicked href into div)

```
$('.contacts a').click(function() {
  var url= $(this).attr('href');
  $('#currentpage').html('loading...');
  $.ajax({
     url: url
  }).success(function(data) {
     $('#currentpage').html(data);
  });       
  return false;
});
//JSBin http://jsbin.com/ucobuv/3/edit
//No need for the allLinks variable here
```

old answer: (load all links)

```
(function getContent(i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: allLinks[i++]
    }).success(function(data) {
        $('#currentpage').append(data);
        if(allLinks[i]) getContent(i);
    });
})(0);
//JSBin http://jsbin.com/ucobuv/1/edit
```

Comment: Please be aware that index.php#contact1 will fetch the enitre index.php therefore lending the same result as index.php#contact2 (hashes are not part of the http protocol but an html/browser convention, they and are not sent over in the request)

Comment: I have this covered, that's not an issue. I suppose targeting of exact elements from returned Ajax data is possible with „find“ jQuery funcion like: var myContent = $(data).find('#mycontent').children() Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have tried it and it ends at first URL, it doesn't continue to another one, which should also append. Any clue?
Also, to URL formats – actually, there is no hash in them, it's simply like:
index.php?id=XYZ

Comment: Aah, I have found that if I use ie. (0,15) at the end of function, all URLs are fetched. Is there more effective way? Thanks!

Comment: it will fetch all the urls of the allLinks array, works fine here http://jsbin.com/ucobuv/1/edit

Comment: Oh ok I guess you want something different then (the "looping" reference in your question got me confused), I'm gonna change the answer now.